# Gone, too, are the days when interviews with figures

Tags: inversion

I saw this sentence [on BBC news website](http://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-34511999), but I don't understand what it means:

> "**Gone, too, are the days** when interviews with figures of the stature of Martin Luther King Jr, Malcolm X and Jimmy Carter made the magazine  so culturally and politically significant."

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/209865/gone-are-the-days. Gone are the days means the matter does not exist these days. In other words, it's an old story

Comment: @MaulikV - I wouldn't use "old story" when explaining this idiom. For example, in this case, _gone are the days_ **is** the story, and that story is brand new. "Old story" implies last year's news. "Gone are the days" implies something has changed – perhaps gradually over time, but it could be a sudden change, too.

Comment: Gone are the days when we used to pay heavy charges for making international calls - how do you take it? @J.R. I think adding 'too' means the example of J Carter is the second example or added example. What I meant by 'old story' is 'old thing' that does not exist anymore

Answer (score 4):

The phrase *gone are the days when XYZ* means that something has changed – it means that XYZ is no more. For example:

- Gone are the days when you needed an operator to place a phone call.
- Gone are the days when caddies stood ready at the first tee of every golf course.

The first sentence is reflecting on advances in telecommunications, the second is explaining the impact of the golf cart.

The sentence you found is saying that the magazine is no longer culturally and politically significant – either because the magazine no longer has feature interviews with leading political figures, or (if the magazine *does* still print such interviews) because those interviews don't spark magazine sales like they used to.

Answer (score 4):

The inverted word order places rhetorical emphasis on **gone**.

> Gone are the days when dinosaurs roamed the earth.
>   The days are gone when dinosaurs roamed the earth.

That time has passed. Which time?  The time when dinosaurs roamed the earth.

**Gone, too, are the days when ...**

In addition to something else which is gone, the days are gone when...

P.S. In this case, the "something else" is pictures of women nude aka pictures of nude women aka pictures of women in the nude aka nude pictures of women.